# Keras: "local variable 'val_ins' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, keras

I'm training a basic image classifier with seven classes, and I'm getting a Python error in Fit which I can't find other people talking about.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

imageSide = 256

def buildAndTrainNetwork():
    classifier = Sequential()

    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (imageSide, imageSide, 3), activation = 'relu', data_format="channels_last"))

    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

    classifier.add(Flatten())

    classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 7, activation = 'sigmoid'))

    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    labelList = [('CarHatchback', [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]), ('CarMinivan', [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]), ('CarPickup', [0,0,1,0,0,0,0]), ('CarSaloon', [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]), ('CarSmart', [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]), ('CarSports', [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]), ('CarVan', [0,0,0,0,0,0,1])]

    train_data = []
    train_labels = []

    test_data = []


    for label,labelData in labelList:
        dir = "mlData/train/" + label

        for img in os.listdir(dir):
            path = os.path.join(dir, img)
            img = Image.open(path)
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            img = img.resize((imageSide, imageSide), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            img = np.array(img)

            train_data.append(img)
            train_labels.append(labelData)


    for label,labelData in labelList:
        dir = "mlData/test/" + label

        for img in os.listdir(dir):
            path = os.path.join(dir, img)
            img = Image.open(path)
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            img = img.resize((imageSide, imageSide), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            img = np.array(img)

            test_data.append(img)

    train_data = np.array(train_data)
    test_data = np.array(test_data)
    train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

    print("Training shape:")
    print(train_data.shape)
    print("Train labels shape:")
    print(train_labels.shape)
    print("Testing shape:")
    print(test_data.shape)

    classifier.fit(
        train_data,
        train_labels,
        steps_per_epoch=8000,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=test_data,
        validation_steps=800
    )


#

buildAndTrainNetwork()
```

The error I receive is:

> File
>   "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1034, in fit
>       val_ins=val_ins, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val_ins' referenced before assignment

FYI, the shape output is:

```
Training shape:
(3502, 256, 256, 3)

Train labels shape:
(3502, 7)

Testing shape:
(3506, 256, 256, 3)
```

I'm assuming that I haven't formatted the input data correctly, but I'm struggling to see the actual error.

Comment: This error shouldn't be seen from a library. If it is, there is usually a bug in it. Luckily there has been a change to exactly [that line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blame/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1035) in code a few months ago, so make sure to use the most recent version of keras.

Comment: Looking at the code there should still be some conditions in which `val_inputs` is not set. Look at the conditions in code an avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validation_data` in `classifier.fit` should be a tuple with the test images (which you have) and the test labels, which you have but forgot to load.

```
for label,labelData in labelList:
    dir = "mlData/test/" + label

    for img in os.listdir(dir):
        # ...

        test_data.append(img)
        test_labels.append(labelData)  # add this
```

Then

```
classifier.fit(
    validation_data=(test_data, test_labels)
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you.  That has moved along to a different error, so I think my data format for validation_data is still incorrect:
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3506 arrays

Comment: In fact, I have fixed that.  Thank you.